# Получение информации об оборудовании Linux

Tags: память, процессор, c, linux

Требуется разработать `Linux` приложение для получения полной информации о процессоре, модулях памяти и материнской платы.

В данном вопросе мне не требуется полное решение поставленной задачи, а всего лишь часть, возможно подсказку или направление в котором следует мыслить.......

Мне нужно получить информации допустим о процессоре и это реализовать в программе, т.е. не через терминал......

Затем я знаю что в системе есть файлы `cpuinfo`, но они не подходят, так как все нужно получить самому, не через терминал и не считывая те файлы, возможно есть какие нибудь структуры например такие как `sysinfo`?

Answer (score 5):

`/proc/cpuinfo` - это не просто файл. Это такой спецфайл, при попытке чтения которого, система сама налету генерит все данные. Использовать подобный "файл" - нормально.

Есть такая утилита - dmidecode (она вроде штатно идет в поставке линукса). У нее есть [сорцы](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/dmidecode/). Но этот подход будет требовать рутовых прав.

Comment: Ну вот, а мне нужно на языке С написать код то как вы сказали "система сама налету генерит все данные"

Comment: как это самому ? в обход ядра ? вы поймите, в линуксе этот "файл" и есть интерфейс к ядру.

Comment: @Владимир911 вот программа dmidecode написана на С, там один файл исходников (!!!) + makefile. Берите и модифицируйте под себя.